# How can we do UI automation testing only using C# without any third party tool?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, ui-automation

I have one issue,currently i am using selenium web driver from .Net C#  for UI automation. can we do same task without using selenium web driver? is that any other way to do same task by using .Net C# only? i want to work only on .Net without using any third party automation tool.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft UI Automation might be an option.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation

[Using UI Automation for Automated Testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This can work fine for Internet Explorer (I've not tested Edge), unfortunately, it doesn't really work for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way for

> work only on .Net without using any third party automation tool.

You can take a look at [Coded UI Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx#verifyingcodeusingcuitcreate) in Visual Studio. There is an integration for [Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286580.aspx) and you'll be able to run them in your [build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx) as well.

Further more there is a [Performance and Stress Testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540(v=vs.110).aspx) with Visual Studio to help you determine how well the SUT responds to various levels of usage. The [Excel reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997707.aspx) is very rich (metrics) and business friendly.

[image]